# How to set pyramiding for each long order

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

Let's say I have two distinct buy conditions.

```
buy1 = abc
sell1 = xyz
buy2 = qwe
sell2 = rty
```

and I have two different entries for long orders.

```
if buy1
   strategy.entry("EL1",true)
if sell1
   strategy.close("EL1")
if buy2
   strategy.entry("EL2",true)
if sell2
   strategy.close("EL2")
```

Now what I want is, I want to set pyramiding for buy1 and buy2 separately. I want buy1 to be executed 3 times max and buy2 to be executed 4 times max.

How would I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store number of entries to some `var` variables, increment them each time when they are less than desired number of entry calls for corresponding entries.

```
//@version=4
strategy("strategy", pyramiding = 100)

cond1 = open>close
cond2 = open<close

var en1 = 0
var en2 = 0


if cond1
    if en1 < 3
        strategy.entry("EL1",true)
        en1+=1

if cond2
    if en2 < 4
        strategy.entry("EL2",true)
        en2+=1
```

after that with your `sell` condition nullify them.

```
if sell1
   strategy.close("EL1")
   en1:=0

if sell2
   strategy.close("EL2")
   en2:=0

plot(close)
```